# Getting errors using Acro for abbreviations and acronyms: Undefined Control Sequence in acro.sty

Tags: expl3, acronyms, acro, bugs

I've been trying to use `acro` for abbreviating terms in a report. It mostly works but each compile requires intervention to complete and does something to my first page, leaves an =1 and a page break. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[A4, 12pt]{article}

% for abbreviations and acronyms
\usepackage[first-style=long]{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{ma}{
  short = MA ,
  long  = Multiple Access ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{noma}{
  short = NOMA ,
  long  = Non-Orthongonal Multiple Access ,
}

% title info
\title{Beamforming for Millimeter-wave \acs{noma}}
\author{Cian Dowd}
\date{21/01/2019}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle

% ABSTRACT
\begin{abstract}
    In this paper\ldots
\end{abstract}

% TABLE OF CONTENTS
\tableofcontents

% LIST OF ACRONYMS
\printacronyms

% INTRODUCTION
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{Introduction}
\ac{noma}\ldots


% LITERATURE REVIEW
\setcounter{section}{1}
\section{Background/ Literature Review}

% Background on Current MA
\subsection{Existing \acf{ma}}

\end{document}
```

This yields the following document; errors shown below it.

[image: stray '1']
`page break`
[image: body of Tex]

I get these messages, ending with the errors:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acro/acro.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e
.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtempla
te.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-abspage.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty))
Runaway argument?
{\bool_if:NT \l__acro_sort_bool {\cs_new_protected:Npn \acro_sort_prop:NN \ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \g@addto@macro.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.2965                         = \c_minus_one
```

This corresponds to line 2965 of acro.sty, though I am not sure why nor do I know how to fix this issue.
Relevant snippet of acro.sty below:

```
        \seq_sort:Nn \l__acro_tmpa_seq
          {
            \int_compare:nTF
              {
                \acro_strcmp:nn
                  { \str_fold_case:n {##1} }
                  { \str_fold_case:n {##2} }
                    = \c_minus_one
              }
              { \sort_return_same: }
              { \sort_return_swapped: }
          }
```

Comment: See https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/116/acro-errors-due-to-update-c_minus_one

Comment: @moewe Am I right in saying that recommends changing the contents of the file to a -1? Makes me a bit uncomfortable but I'll give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: Directly editing `acro.sty` would be a last resort, but I can't find a more elegant work-around at the moment since `\c_minus_one` is used in an `\AtBeginDocument` hook, that does not quite lend itself to patching.

Comment: @moewe I did that and it worked perfectly. Not ideal, as you said, but much appreciated. Thanks a lot. Care to write that as an answer?

Comment: The [bug 116](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/116/acro-errors-due-to-update-c_minus_one)  was fixed in acro 2.9 on 2019-02-17

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constant `\c_minus_one` was removed from LaTeX3 in the end-of-year deprecation round for 2018. `acro.sty` is still using it, though, and that causes issues with new versions of the LaTeX3 kernel. See https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/116/acro-errors-due-to-update-c_minus_one.

You could manually edit `acro.sty` and change the `\c_minus_one` to `-1`. Keep in mind, however, that usually edits like this to distributed files are strongly discouraged. In this case the edit could be justified because the file is unusable without it and an updated version of `acro.sty` that would make the fix unnecessary would overwrite your fixed version.

You could also reinstate the command (similar to https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/c96faed90a5a63ba84695190560bdacac1dfdacc#diff-645783629830bdaaeede08f6ea12cb15) before `acro` is loaded.

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tex_let:D \c_minus_one \scan_stop:
\int_const:Nn \c_minus_one {-1}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% for abbreviations and acronyms
\usepackage[first-style=long]{acro}
```

*edit* [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) kindly suggested a streamlined version of my original suggestion.

I guess the LaTeX3 team don't really want to see that either, so until `acro` gets fixed by the maintainer you are stuck with several bad options.

Comment: `\tex_let:D \c_minus_one \scan_stop:` and `\int_const:Nn \c_minus_one {-1}` is easier.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the suggestion. Edited it in.

Comment: a fixed `acro` is on its way to CTAN

Comment: @clemens this means we can entirely get rid of the additional code provided in this answer, right? or should we do anything else?

Comment: @clemens and the macro `\c_one` is less likely to be deprecated in a future deprecation round as `\c_minus_one`, correct?