# Glossaries and Index are not Printed at the end of document

Tags: glossaries, imakeidx, makeindex

I am writing a book and trying to produce glossaries at the end of document using the package glossaries. No glossaries are printed at the end of the document, neither index is produced at the end. MWE is given below:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{newtxtext}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{imakeidx}
    \makeindex[options=-s index, columns=2]
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=5cm, inner=2cm, headsep=4pt]{geometry}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \singlespacing
    \usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
    \makeglossaries
    \input{glossary_FIM}
    \begin{document}
        \title{A \LaTeX Document}
        \author{Ahmed Arif}

        \maketitle
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \Gls{abs} are securities issued against assets. \index{ABS}
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
    \printindex
    \end{document}
```

Whereas, the gloosary_FIM.tex contains following entry.

```
            \newglossaryentry{abs}{%
            name={Asset-Backed Securities},%
                description={These are the securities issued by a special purpose vehicle.}}
```

Comment: Have you tried typesetting the .tex twice?

Comment: What is meant by typesetting the .tex twice?

Comment: I.e. pressing the green "Typeset" button in your editor.

Comment: You mean compiling twice?

Comment: Yes, sometimes for me it works out the issues.

Comment: I tried but it did not work

Comment: When I compile your MWE, I get errors discussed [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470145/getting-errors-using-acro-for-abbreviations-and-acronyms-undefined-control-sequ](here)

Comment: This is a problem related to acro package. I have already fixed the issue discussed in the link you shared. The problem is not with acro package. Perhaps I should remove the acro package entries from the MWE.

Comment: `glossaries` requires running of the `makeglossaries` perl script as well -- just pressing `typesetting` in obscure editors is not enough. Alternatively, use `\makenoidxnoglossaries` instead of `\makeglossaries`

Comment: @Christian can you please guide me how to run '\makeglossaries'

Comment: @AhmedArif: I don't run such editors as you are using apparently -- I call `makeglossaries` in my Linux Console in a typical Linux tool chain, i.e. `pdflatex foo.tex ; makeglossaries foo ; pdflatex foo.tex`